# How to add items to ArrayList from Firebase database listener

Tags: android

I am using ArrayList as the data provider, with RecyclerView (GridLayout manager). I want to add items to to this ArrayList from a Firebase event listener, whenever a change occurs. But the items won't add. this is the code:

```
 private ArrayList<String> myDataset = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nb, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

     ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            myDataset.add("Data"); // does not add from here



           // more code here. . .
    } 
 }     

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

   //if i add the data here it works:
    myDataset.add("Data");
    return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have created a listener but not attached it to any `DatabaseReference`. Thus, it is never called. Please follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) if you are new to Firebase. The attachment of a listener to a reference is what triggers the query, and subsequent data retrieval.

Also keep in mind that this retrieval is asynchronous, so initially when you set the adapter it will be empty. Later, your local copy of `myDataset` will get populated by the callbacks, but you must have a method in your Adapter class that allows it to update its stored ArrayList. Then the adapter will have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` (or similar methods) in order to update the display.

You should be able to find a number of tutorials online regarding this sort of functionality.